# How do I recursively split a linked list of integers into an odd and even list in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Hey I just took a quiz in school involving linked lists with C++ and I couldn't figure out how to get the function to work in the way my prof wanted. The quiz is over but I'd like to solve it anyways and try to understand linked lists better. I've been trying to figure this out for like 3 hours so, help would be appreciated.

odd_even needed to have this signature and needed to be a recursive solution. h is the original linked list passed in and nodes are split into the odd and even lists. odd and even are initially set to nullptr and odd_even sets the original list h to nullptr after it's completed the split. He also said it was to be a deconstructive solution, no creating new lists or nodes. I'm not 100% clear on that but I took it to mean I should only manipulate/reassign existing nodes.

I've tried many things, but this was what I submitted:

```
node* odd_even(node* p, node*& odd, node*& even) {
    if (!p) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else if (p->data % 2 == 0) {
        even = p;
        even->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even->next);
    }
    else {
        odd = p;
        odd->next = odd_even(p->next, odd->next, even);
    }
    return p;
}
int main() {
    node* odd = nullptr;
    node* even = nullptr;
    node* h = new node{ 1, new node{3, new node{5, new node{6, new node{8, new node{9, nullptr} } } } } };
    printr(h);
    h = odd_even(h, odd, even);
    printr(h);
    printr(odd);
    printr(even);

}
```

```
Expected Input:
node* h: 1->3->5->6->8->9->nullptr
node* odd, even: nullptr.

Expected Output:
h: 1->3->5->6->8->9->nullptr
h = odd_even(h, odd, even)
h: nullptr
even: 6->8->nullptr
odd: 1->3->5->9->nullptr
```

I tried finding the next node for each list through tail recursive calls, but that breaks down when it switches from odd to even assignment call or vice versa. I tried making my recursive calls up to the end of the list then split them up on the way back, but then grabbing the first node was difficult and I don't think thats the solution anyways. I also had issues getting the whole thing to ultimately return a nullptr... I just don't think I'm approaching it right and I could use a bit of guidance here. Thanks!

---

Update:
I spent another few hours on it and came up with 2 solutions. 1 is better than the other pretty sure. Thanks for the feedback guys, I'm happy I did figure it out by myself a bit first. I look forward to reading the comments, I'm sure theres better ways to go about it than I have.

My first solution (concise but doesn't return nullptr for the original list at the end...):

```
node* odd_even(node* p, node*& odd, node*& even) {
    if (!p) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    p->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even);
    if (p->data % 2 == 0 ) {
        p->next = even;
        even = p;
    }else {
        p->next = odd;
        odd = p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

My second solution (a bit of a mess but fulfills all the requirments):

```
node* odd_even(node* p, node*& odd, node*& even) {
        if (!p) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        if (p->data % 2 == 0) {
            even = p;
        }else {
            odd = p;
        }
        if (p->next) {
            if (p->next->data % 2 == 0) {
                if (even) {
                    even->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even->next);
                }else {
                    even = odd_even(p->next, odd, even);
                }
            }else {
                if (odd) {
                    odd->next = odd_even(p->next, odd->next, even);
                }else {
                    odd = odd_even(p->next, odd, even);
                }
            }
            return p;
        }
        even->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even);
        odd->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even);
}
```

Comment: If you move the head node from one list to another, you take all its successors with it unless you fix up its next pointer. However, if you move the tail node, there is nothing to fix up. So handle the tail case first.

Comment: You can't have an end-result where the node with value `5` having a `next` that points to `6` in `h` and pointing to `9` in `odd` without having 2 separate `node`s both containing (or at least pointing to) the value 5. So not creating new nodes seems to be a non-starter with your current design.

Comment: A note about actual programs: List algorithms should *not* be implemented recursively in C++ because they have O(N) recursion depth which easily overflows the limited call stack with large lists. Recursive list functions are reasonable only in some functional languages that guarantee tail call optimisation (such as Haskell for example).

Comment: @eerorika yeah you're right, but my professor just wants us to be able to do things recursively. So yeah I probably would do this iteratively if it were a personal project, but for learning purposes I gotta do everything recursively lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`odd_even()` created two new lists by rewiring one old list.

So far, so good.

Unfortunately, while you put all the nodes from the old list where they belong, you forgot terminating them by setting the final next-pointer to null. Thus, one will have the original last node and is thus terminated, while the other links to some node from the other list.

Where do you terminate? Well, just before returning null.

Also, you should either return null directly, or by tail-recursion.

```
node* odd_even(node* p, node*& odd, node*& even) noexcept {
    if (!p) {
        odd = even = nullptr;
        return nullptr;
    } else if (p->data % 2) {
        odd = p;
        return odd_even(p->next, p->next, even);
    } else {
        even = p;
        return odd_even(p->next, odd, p->next);
    }
}
```

By the way, this is a terrible demonstration for recursion, as the iterative version is even simpler, and doesn't depend on the compiler to eliminate recursive calls, which it should do here as a matter of *quality of implementation*.

```
node* odd_even(node* p, node*& odd, node*& even) noexcept {
    auto p_odd = &odd, p_even = &even;
    for (; p; p = p->next) {
        auto& chosen = p->data % 2 ? p_odd : p_even;
        *chosen = p;
        chosen = &p->next;
    }
    *p_odd = *p_even = nullptr;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Okay good to know I wasn't completely off there. Just gotta get used to the linked list logic here. I noticed that you passed in p->next instead of even->next or odd->next in the recursive calls. Wouldn't that cause issues since p is passed in by value whereas odd and even are by reference? Then in later recursive calls you're just manipulating the original list p not the odd or even lists no? Or maybe my sparse knowledge of C++ is showing lol. And thanks for the efficiency tips. Obviously in university they just want me to prove I can write recursion. I would no doubt write this iteratively.

Comment: `p->next` and `even->next` (or `odd->next`, depending on which block) refer to the *exact same* object. Thus, it doesn't matter aside from esthetics, and guess which I like better? In later recursive calls, I pass a link to the next node to be spliced, and the places where they could be spliced. the rest of the output-lists are already done and thus irrelevant. And they should still make the effort to provide not completely idiotic examples, but yes, that's expecting a bit much.

Comment: lol okay I'll stare at it a bit longer and figure it out. Still getting used to the pointer stuff. And yeah haha idk man its just like that. Gotta do everything the hard way I suppose. I don't mind too much. I like a challenge =)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the even case (odd has the same problem)

```
even = p;
even->next = odd_even(p->next, odd, even->next);
```

You have the same value in `p` and `even`, so they have the same `->next`

You need to unlink `p` from the list to process it. I don't know why your instructor wants `odd_even` to return a `node *`, as it should always return a null pointer.

```
even = p;
node * next = p->next;
p->next = nullptr;
odd_even(next, odd, p->next);
```

You can simplify that with [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange)

```
even = p;
odd_even(std::exchange(p->next, nullptr), odd, p->next);
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3662e0e4bcc05ca5)

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah it's ultimately supposed to return as a null pointer, but the return type is node* in order to have us do a recursive solution. Honestly the problem isn't difficult to solve, it's just the constraints that were messing with me. And I just learned about pointers so... Anyways thanks for the answer, things make some more sense now =)